# Update data with LinQ to SQL not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My db table was Student, couldn't update after I press the update button. Data still the same.

```
 string name = txtName.Text;
 string dob = txtDOB.Text;
 string tel = txtTelephone.Text;
 string address = txtAddress.Text;
 string email = User.Identity.Name;

 Student stud = db.Students.Single(u => u.StudentEmail == email);

 stud.Name = name;
 stud.DateOfBirth = dob;
 stud.Telephone = tel;
 stud.Address = address;

 db.SubmitChanges();

 Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about db ?

Comment: Are you getting any exception, and are you sure you are storing Dates as string because it is not a good idea.

Comment: @Tommo1977 My db are all string variables, I already test to response.write(), all string is appeared, only this update cannot proceed. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Habib DateOfBirth is key in by user, example 1990-01-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set the state of modification, before of "SubmitChanges"(SaveChanges):

```
db.Entry(stud).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the table has a Primary Key - if it doesn't, there is no way for LINQ to SQL to formulate the required `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: My Primary Key is Email.

Comment: In your `dbml` and in the database?

Comment: Yes. `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [StudentEmail] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Password]     VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Name]         VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth]  VARCHAR (15)  NOT NULL,
    [Telephone]    VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Address]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [NoticeStatus] BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Status]       BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentEmail] ASC)
);`